# Uniform convergence of $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}.e^{-(x-n)^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $f_n:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f_n(x)=\frac{1}{n}.e^{-(x-n)^2},n\geq 1$.

Prove  that $\sum_{n} f_n$ converges uniformly in $\mathbb{R}$.

I want to prove that: $R_n(x)=\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}f_k(n)\underset{n\infty}{\rightarrow}0$

I have $(R_n(x))^2=\left ( \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}e^{-(x-k)^2} \right )^2\leq \left ( \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2} \right )\left ( \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}e^{-2(x-k)^2} \right )$.

$\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}\leq \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k(k-1)}=\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{k-1}-\frac{1}{k})=\frac{1}{n}$.

I want to find $a$ and prove that: $\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}e^{-2(x-k)^2}\leq a$.

Could you give me some hints? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

For every $x\geq1$ let $l$ be the integer part of $x$, that is, $l\leq x<l+1$.
If $k\geq l+1$, then $0\leq k-l-1\leq k-x$ and so $-(k-x)^{2}\leq-(k-l-1)^{2}%
$. We can estimate
$$
\sum_{k=l+1}^{\infty}e^{-2(k-x)^{2}}\leq\sum_{k=l+1}^{\infty}e^{-2(k-l-1)^{2}%
}=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}e^{-2m^{2}},
$$
where $m=k-l-1$. Similarly, if $k\leq l$, then $0\leq l-k\leq x-k$ and so
$-(k-x)^{2}\leq-(l-k)^{2}$. We can estimate the finite sum
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{l}e^{-2(k-x)^{2}}\leq\sum_{k=1}^{l}e^{-2(l-k)^{2}}=\sum
_{m=0}^{l-1}e^{-2m^{2}}\leq\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}e^{-2m^{2}},
$$
where $m=l-k$. Combining these inequalities we have
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}e^{-2(k-x)^{2}}=\sum_{k=l+1}^{\infty}e^{-2(k-x)^{2}}%
+\sum_{k=1}^{l}e^{-2(k-x)^{2}}\leq2\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}e^{-2m^{2}}.
$$
If $x\le 1$ it should be simpler. You just use the first estimate with $l=1$